# How to make embed cpython interpreter in wpf

Tags: c#, python, wpf

I am currently creating a Python IDE using C # and wpf.
So I try to create a Python interpreter, but when I browse the internet, I do not get the answer and I want to ask.

1. How do I create a python interpreter using wpf and C #?
2. How do I create a Python console window that has real-time inputs and outputs? [this is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxO0l.png)

My question is both. I'll wait for answers. Thank you and Have a nice day.

Comment: You could go look in open source IDE projects to see how they do it, then port the principle to C#/WPF. Or instead of creating the console window from scratch, just reuse an existing solution: if you start a process, you can embed the entire window of that process in your application.

Comment: Or, if you don't really need CPython, use IronPython which probably has most functionality you want allready, and is written in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a Console Window. Off course with little bit of tweaking on itemStyle you can achieve what you required from this Xaml.

```
    <Grid Background="Black">
    <ListView Background="Black" x:Name="lstView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="420" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="792">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="792"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListBox.Items>
            <TextBox Background="Black" Foreground="White" Name="currentText" Height="23" Text="TextBox" Width="773" BorderThickness="0" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"/>
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListView>
```

[image]

And in Code Behind.

```
    private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Content = currentText.Text;
            RunScript(currentText.Text); // Send it to Python and get the result back
            l.Width = 792;
            l.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            if (lstView.Items.Count == 1)
                lstView.Items.Insert(0, l);
            else
                lstView.Items.Insert(lstView.Items.Count-1, l);
            currentText.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }

    /// This is sample
    private void RunScript(string text)
    {
        try
          {
             // the Python Interpreter with the text
          } 
         Catch(Exception Ex)
         {
         }
    }
```

For executing Python scripts, you can use IronPython. Install the IronPython Nuget Package.

https://medium.com/emoney-engineering/running-python-script-from-c-and-working-with-the-results-843e68d230e5

Comment: @Heonoh was it useful ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was able to create a python console. Thank you. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Heonoh Glad I was able to help you !

Comment: Thank you for your help